# Knockout binding a font awesome icon to a property

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I'm attempting to display a font awesome icon based on a property whilst looping through a knockout observable array.

Current code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: TimeToPutAwaySummary">
    <tr class="noOfPeopleRequiredRow">
        <td data-bind="text: $data.IsOptimumNoOfPeople ? '***' + $data.NoOfPeopleRequiredText + '***' : $data.NoOfPeopleRequiredText">
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right" data-bind="text: $data.Time"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This currently works such that it outputs:

```
1 Person Required
*** 2 Person Required ***
3 Person Required
4 Person Required
5 Person Required
```

However, I want to display a font awesome icon instead of the '***' i.e. something like this:

```
1 Person Required
(font awesome icon) 2 Person Required
3 Person Required
4 Person Required
5 Person Required
```

I've tried the following but that doesn't display an icon:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: TimeToPutAwaySummary">
    <tr class="noOfPeopleRequiredRow">
        <td data-bind="text: $data.IsOptimumNoOfPeople ? '***' + $data.NoOfPeopleRequiredText + '***' : $data.NoOfPeopleRequiredText">
            <span data-bind="visible: IsOptimumNoOfPeople"><i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right" data-bind="text: $data.Time"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I also tried to replace the `span` tag with a `p` tag.

Comment: Why don't use a <span> with your data-bind="text:..." instead putting it in your td?

Comment: @Tistkle How so? I believe <span> tags can't be embedded in <tr> tags. I've got a table with two columns as shown in the above code. Column 1 has the 'x' Person Required text and column 2 has a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using `<td data-bind="text: $data....>` on your `td`, this wil overwrite all content inside the element thus your icon-span-tag is ignored & removed. try moving the data-bind away from your td like following copy/paste code:

```
<td>
 <span data-bind="text: $data.IsOptimumNoOfPeople ? '***' + $data.NoOfPeopleRequiredText + '***' : $data.NoOfPeopleRequiredText"></span>
 <span data-bind="visible: IsOptimumNoOfPeople"><i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</td>
```

Or better yet just remove the data-bind on your td since that's going to be replaced with your font-awesome icon..  :)